# how can i disable a button from another view controller using restoration id in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

How can I disable a button from another class, using button `restorationID`?

My view controller calls a class for `NSStream` and if the stream is found, I want to disable the button for connect.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Im not clear on what it has to be done via a restoration ID.. why not any other callback pattern (ie. blocks, protocols, observers)

Comment: i've solved it already, how can i close the question?

Comment: You shouldn't close it - you're allowed to post the answer to your own question so that people after you will benefit from it. (If you really used restorationID, that is.)